Change handling of quoted strings (disable apostrophe in CC mode)?
I'm editing code in a domain-specific language using CC mode. This generally works well, except that the single-quote character (apostrophe, U + 0027) in this language is used to specify a word size (32'd0 is a 32-bit decimal integer).
CC mode interprets this as the start of a string, and turns on string font lock handling until the next single-quote is encountered.
Is there a relatively easy way to turn this off, so that a single quote is treated as an ordinary character?
